# How add class to p elements which generated by linebreaks?

Tags: python, django

I user next line in my template: `{{ description|linebreaks }}`

How to add the same class to all `<p>` elements which will be generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: place your text with linebreaks in wrapper element with class which assign needed style to all inner `<p>` elements:

```
<style>
    .linebreaks p {
         font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="linebreaks">{{ description|linebreaks }}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by modifying template processors, but if you want to add this to *all* `<p>` elements which are generated why not just use CSS?

Comment: An possible solution for CSS is generating the linebreaks in an div element and then give all p elements of that element an style.